# How to smooth out a stucco exterior?

Tags: stucco

We have stucco on the exterior of the house. It is a sand/float finish, I believe, and it looks like this.  It is a medium to coarse version of this finish.

How do I go about making this smooth by doing it myself?
Do I have to scrape off the existing stucco or can I actually just put a layer on top of it and fill in the gaps until I have a smooth exterior?

[image: sand/float finish]

Comment: I am not sure so, this is why it is a comment. If it is unpainted EIFS, go over it again with your preferred texture/surface. If it is true stucco you would need to treat it like is is a bare wall, or strip it all off to a bare wall, depending on what thickness you can tolerate.

Comment: It is true stucco on top of plaster walls I believe. The stucco has paint on it.

Comment: The paint will mess you up on keeping it simple...

Answer (score 1):

I would pressure wash the entire surface with plain water. Make sure to keep about 18 inches away from the surface and use a wide fan tip. You want to wash it well, but you don't want to peel off any of the material. Allow the surface to dry for 2-3 days.

If the stucco is structurally sound and there is no loose or peeling paint, you can use a bonding agent such as [**Weld-Crete**](http://www.larsenproducts.com/frequently-asked-questions/). Then you can apply new stucco right over the top of your existing finish.

[**Kirk Giordano**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EuT83BNWctI) is one of the country's greatest plastering companies and he has many videos that detail how to get a variety of finishes.

[image]